# High Voltage Supply Use

Tags: high-voltage

I have some quires regarding High Voltage supply uses:

1. Is there any power supply which can operate in the range of 90VAC-600VAC?
2. If i have my high voltage supply in the range 300VAC-600VAC and i will give lower voltage in the range 110VAC-300VAC to Supply( it will not give out put) then there will be any malfunction in the power supply.

   3. Is there any ac device or fuse type which can protect the high voltage supply in the in lower voltage no to give power to it. when voltage cross 270 V it power the supply.

Please provide me solution regarding this!!!

Comment: Please provide links to the datasheets for your power supplies.  Otherwise, we have only a vague idea about them.

Comment: you can refer this power supply with part code as:DRP024V060W

Comment: @d.rudra No, you can provide a link to the data sheet!

Comment: @Nick, you can refer this    http://www.northstardatasheet.com/datasheet/31_20130329_024911012_Technical_Datasheet_DRP024V060W3BX_Rev.00_2013.03.pdf

Comment: "Is there ... " appears to be a shopping question not a question about how to design such a PSU.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Not now.
2. If you dont supply enough input voltage the power supply will definitely mal-function. The input range you mentioned here is the minimum and maximum voltages. But the nominal voltage is what the manufacturer recommends for stable operation of the power supply and it is 400VAC.
3. You can design a micro-controller based switching circuit for this purpose.

Comment: If i use switching circuit using microcontroller may be my controller get reset when switching supply of microcontroller,

Comment: @d.rudra A micro-controller needs 5 Volts or less. A 5 V output can be obtained from 7.5 Volts input and so on.. It is the only better solution to this issue. Use a 30 V step down transformer and a 5 V regulator IC. Use it to supply the micro-controller. Even if the input AC supply decreases the regulator will supply a 5 V dc which can run the micro-controller.

Comment: you are right but there will be requirement of 30 step down transformer which can operate on wide range 90-600 VAC.